# How to completely remove an icon from JDialog?

Tags: java, icons, jdialog

I am creating a dialog for showing a progress of files' copying. What I want to do is to completely remove dialog's icon image.

I created such kind of dialogs before providing an application's instance of `FrameView` as an argument for `JDialog`'s constructor like this:

```
public class MyAppView extends FrameView {

    // ...

    @Action
    public void showOptionsDialog() {

        // Creating modal options' dialog
        JDialog optionsDialog = new JDialog(this, true);

        // ...
    }
}
```

So, as I can see, I need a parent component to make my dialog with no icon. In my current case (when I have no parent frame view) I tried the following hack method setting a transparent icon but it doesn't work as I expect - I still see an empty area for an icon in dialog's title bar and (what's the worst) I still have a popup window when I click this area.

```
JFrame dummyFrame = new JFrame();
Image icon = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
dummyFrame.setIconImage(icon);
JDialog myDialog = new JDialog(dummyFrame, true);
```

Anyway, it must be possible to remove an icon. The working example is [JOptionPane](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/0960__JOptionPane-Dialog.htm):

```
JOptionPane.showMessage(null, "My message");
```

Looking at `JOptionPane`'s source code one can find that static `Frame JOptionPane.getRootFrame()` is used to get a parent for the calls when parent component is set to `null`:

```
public static Frame getRootFrame() throws HeadlessException {
    Frame sharedFrame = 
        (Frame)SwingUtilities.appContextGet(sharedFrameKey);
    if (sharedFrame == null) {
        sharedFrame = SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame();
        SwingUtilities.appContextPut(sharedFrameKey, sharedFrame);
    }
    return sharedFrame;
}
```

So I've also tried to create my dialog as follows:

```
JDialog myDialog = new JDialog(JOptionPane.getRootFrame(), true);
```

but there is still no success. I have a standard Java icon when I try to apply this code snippet.

And my question is: what am I doing wrong? **How to completely remove an icon of `JDialog` as it is done by `JOptionPane`?**

P.S. I use JDK6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to make a dialog non-resizable and then it will be without an icon with any parent window.

```
JDialog myDialog = new JDialog(new Frame(), true);
myDialog.setResizable(false);
myDialog.setVisible(true);
```

Unfortunately, if your dialog is to be resizable there is no way to remove an icon except of setting a transparent icon.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. Maybe it's because I'm using an ownerless dialog. I used the `JDialog(Window, String, ModalityType)` constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the following is more in the direction you want.

```
            JProgressBar pb = new JProgressBar();
            JOptionPane op = new JOptionPane(pb, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
            JDialog dlg = op.createDialog(MyJFrame.this, "Progress");
            dlg.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

In netbeans with design options:

```
initComponents();
Image img = new BufferedImage(1, 1,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
this.setIconImage(img);
```

Comment: This largely duplicates an existing answer from a few years back. Can you explain how this differs?

Comment: @NathanTuggy This is exactly what the OP tried without success. I flagged it for removal but the moderators rejected my flag.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with the icon (though JDK7 on WindowsXP).
The popup menu on the icon I suppressed in the dialog with **setFocusableWindowState(false)**.

The JFrame like your code:

```
public MyJFrame() {
    //URL url = this.getClass().getResource("transparent.gif");
    //if (url != null) {
    //    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
    //    if (icon != null)
    //        setIconImage(icon.getImage());
    //}
    BufferedImage icon = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
    //icon.setRGB(0, 0, 0x00000000);
    setIconImage(icon);
}
```

and

```
    JFrame dummyFrame = new MyJFrame();
    JDialog myDialog = new JDialog(dummyFrame, true);
    myDialog.setIconImage(dummyFrame.getIconImage()); // Not needed.
    myDialog.setFocusableWindowState(false);
    myDialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Is your dialog's title aligned to the left of the title bar? I see like there is transparent 16x16 icon on the left, so the title seems to be shifted to the right by the width of the icon. `setFocusableWindowState(false)` draws a title bar like it's inactive what is also not desired behavior. Please take a look at `JOptionPane`'s dialogs - they appear like I want.

Comment: Then my answer is no help. Besides setDecorated(false) and drawing the title bar oneself I think the answer is on another line.