# Losing JDialog title when hiding panel (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, joptionpane

EDIT:
Of course I find an answer 2 min after I post a question.
[How to completely remove an icon from JDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504731/how-to-completely-remove-an-icon-from-jdialog)

But follow-up; anyone knows the way to make consistent icon state when changing resizable property?

PS. I can't answer my own question for 8 more hours.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
To put it short, here is an stripped down example code which has a problem.
When I click on "Details" (WinXP x32 java 1.6) jPanel2 changes visibility state and together with jPanel2 for some reason the dialog icon is removed. Quite curious.
Anyone knows why the icon is hidden together with JPanel?
Code is generated by NetBeans 7.1, only slightly adapted to be self-contained.

Thanks in advance for help!

```
import java.awt.Frame;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class TestHide extends javax.swing.JDialog {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public TestHide(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    jPanel2.setVisible(false);
    pack();
  }

  private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    lblIcon = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    taShortMsg = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jSeparator2 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jSeparator3 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    taDetails = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    btnOk = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnTgDetails = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    lblIcon.setText(""); // NOI18N

    jScrollPane1.setBorder(null);

    taShortMsg.setBackground(getBackground());
    taShortMsg.setColumns(20);
    taShortMsg.setEditable(false);
    taShortMsg.setFont(lblIcon.getFont());
    taShortMsg.setLineWrap(true);
    taShortMsg.setRows(5);
    taShortMsg.setBorder(null);
    taShortMsg.setCursor(getCursor());
    taShortMsg.setOpaque(false);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(taShortMsg);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(lblIcon).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 399, Short.MAX_VALUE).addContainerGap()));
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
        jPanel1Layout
            .createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(lblIcon).addContainerGap(54, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))));

    jPanel2.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
      public void componentHidden(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
        jPanel2ComponentHidden(evt);
      }

      public void componentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
        jPanel2ComponentShown(evt);
      }
    });

    jLabel3.setText("jLabel3"); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(jSeparator1).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(jSeparator2).addContainerGap()));
    jPanel3Layout
        .setVerticalGroup(jPanel3Layout
            .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                jPanel3Layout
                    .createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(
                        jPanel3Layout
                            .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10,
                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jSeparator2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10,
                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))).addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
    jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
    jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
        jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(jSeparator3).addContainerGap()));
    jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
        jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(jSeparator3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

    jScrollPane2.setBorder(null);

    taDetails.setColumns(20);
    taDetails.setEditable(false);
    taDetails.setFont(lblIcon.getFont());
    taDetails.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(taDetails);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(jScrollPane2).addContainerGap())
        .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
        javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
        jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 129, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)));

    btnOk.setText("OK"); // NOI18N
    btnOk.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        btnOkActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });

    btnTgDetails.setText("Details"); // NOI18N
    btnTgDetails.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        btnTgDetailsActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout
        .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(
            layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE).addComponent(btnOk, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnTgDetails, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addContainerGap())
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
        layout
            .createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(btnTgDetails)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(btnOk).addContainerGap()))));

    pack();
  }

  private void btnTgDetailsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (jPanel2.isVisible()) {
      btnTgDetails.setText("Details>>");
    } else {
      btnTgDetails.setText("Details<<");
    }
    jPanel2.setVisible(!jPanel2.isVisible());
    this.validate();
    this.pack();
  }

  private void btnOkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    dispose();
  }

  private void jPanel2ComponentHidden(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
    setResizable(false);
  }

  private void jPanel2ComponentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
    setResizable(true);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
          javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestHide.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestHide.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestHide.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestHide.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    showMessageDialog(null, "I am title", "Small message...", "long\n\nlong\nmessage", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  }

  public static void showMessageDialog(Frame parent, String title, String shortMessage, String longMessage, int type) {
    TestHide md = new TestHide(parent, true);
    Icon icon = null;
    switch (type) {
    case JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE:
      icon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
      break;
    case JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE:
      icon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
      break;
    case JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE:
      icon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");
      break;
    }

    md.setTitle(title);
    md.lblIcon.setIcon(icon);
    md.taShortMsg.setText(shortMessage);
    if (longMessage == null) {
      md.btnTgDetails.setVisible(false);
    } else {
      md.taDetails.setText(longMessage);
      md.taDetails.setCaretPosition(0);
    }
    md.pack();
    md.setVisible(true);
  }

  private javax.swing.JButton btnOk;
  private javax.swing.JToggleButton btnTgDetails;
  private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
  private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
  private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
  private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
  private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
  private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
  private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
  private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
  private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator2;
  private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator3;
  private javax.swing.JLabel lblIcon;
  private javax.swing.JTextArea taDetails;
  private javax.swing.JTextArea taShortMsg;
}
```

Comment: did you meaning Java Cup Icon ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the following statement in a constructor like

```
public TestHide(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
super(parent, modal);
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images\\white_title.png"));
initComponents();
jPanel2.setVisible(false);
pack();  }
```

then the icon on title bar appear constantly.

Comment: Thanks, I've used 
`setIconImage(parent.getIconImage());`